# Split but respect comma names

Tags: javascript, string, split, fuse

I'm having a little trouble with a code.
I have a list of words that need to be separated and parsed instead of rows in columns.

This code actually works very well and does that job.
How is actually working:

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Mario, Louigi, Peach",
    "1":"Wario, King Kong, Bomberman",
    "2":"Dracula, Doctor Z, Raikou"
};

const Obj3 = [];

var count = Obj[0].split(", ").length;
var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  
  var string = [];
  
  for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
    string.push(Obj[j].split(", ")[i]);
  }
  
  Obj3[i] = string;
}

console.log(Obj3);
```

But if any name has a comma in the middle example: Mr, Robot it considers that comma as a separator comma and divides Mr, Robot in two instead of one.

Example:

```js
    const Obj = {
        "0":"Mr, Robot, Louigi, Peach",
        "1":"Wario, King Kong, Bomberman",
        "2":"Dracula, Doctor Z, Raikou"
    };

    const Obj3 = [];

    var count = Obj[0].split(", ").length;
    var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

    for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
      
      var string = [];
      
      for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
        string.push(Obj[j].split(", ")[i]);
      }
      
      Obj3[i] = string;
    }

    console.log(Obj3);
```

And then it creates an undefined record that causing me errors.
Any idea how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have four comma delimited strings on the first index of the array, rest of the array have three comma delimited strings.

Comment: Do you control the data format in `Obj`?

Comment: @t0mm13b Yeah, I know that that's why I'm asking for help. Even if there are 4 commas on the first index of the array, one of them it's a "fake" comma. 

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @JohanP Thank you for your answer, the Obj is the result of strings.map(item => (item.value));

Comment: You will have to escape your items, usually with `""` so that you can determine word boundaries. i.e `"Mr, Robot", "Mario"` then look for some regex that will split on commas except inside `""`

Comment: Given your input format it's impossible for code to know which commas you intend to split on and which ones you intend to be part of the name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @JohanP how I Should escape the items? I can show you my format before doing .map and maybe we can add there the quotes?

Comment: @DanielBeck thank you for the answer Daniel, can you please suggest me any format? How should I change my format?

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be squashing array data into a single string in the first place, and your object would look like `{0: ["Mr, Robot", "Mario"], 1: ["Luigi", "Peach]}`.  (Or if the IDs are always just sequential integers as shown here, just use an array of arrays instead of an object.) Alternatively, if you must merge them into a string, use a delimiter that you are certain won't appear in the actual data.

Comment: Hello, @DanielBeck Thank you so much for your help. I'm starting to see the path you are thinking on. It's possible to send you some images and you see how is my data? Thank you!

Comment: @DanielBeck Managed to add quotes to every word. Now need to edit my code to use the new format:

(3) ["Mr, Robot","Wario", "Louigi","King Kong", "Peach","Bomberman"]
0:"Mr, Robot","Wario"
1:"Louigi","King Kong"
2:"Peach","Bomberman"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get the names before they've been joined by commas, you might be able to use a regex delimiter to split them.  For example, if it would suffice to not split at commas preceded by only two non-whitespace characters, you could use:

```
.split(/(?<=[^ ,]{3,}), /)
```

This regex will match `', '` only if it is preceded by at least 3 characters that don't match `' '` or `','`.

Comment: "if it would suffice to not split at commas preceded by only two non-whitespace characters" doesn't seem like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Hello @user3088089, thank you so much for your tip.
Actually, If I do console.log before the map and all the code

It looks like this:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {key: "Field 1", value: "Mr, Robot, Wario"}1: {key: "Field 2", value: "Louigi, King Kong"}2: {key: "Field 3", value: "Peach, Bomberman"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @DanielBeck Clearly the preferred solution would be to get the names unjoined, or else joined by a delimiter that is not present in the names themselves.  This answer was offered as a possible workaround if that is not possible.

Comment: @K3ny1If that is the case, then maybe you can split only on the last comma.  Maybe something like: `.split(/, (?=[^,]+$)/)`